# MSc after Diplome d'Ingenieur

Tags: masters, career-path

I am going to start a Diplome d'Ingenieur in Electronics in Bordeaux, France. Can I do a MSc in Electrical Engineering focused in Photonics after?

Comment: Do you mean an MSc from somewhere outside France? It is already considered to be a masters level diploma. So it would be like a second masters. Is that the question?

Comment: And would a doctorate in EE be preferable?

Comment: Depending on the school and the courses you take you can sometimes ask to swap the last year of the École d'ingénieur for a 2 year master abroad or for the second year of a master degree (M2) in France. That's what I did and ended up with both a french diplôme d'ingénieur and a MSc from a foreign university.

Comment: The school I am going to attend is ENSEIRB MATMECA. The electronics program is focused on RF and microelectronics. My goal is to acquire a solid background in these topics and pursue a MSc/PhD in Photonics to get into an R&D position. French Diplome d'Ingenieur is technically a masters degree, but does not have as much research as a MSc from Canada or US universities.

Comment: The university has exchange agreements with UCL and University of California, which have good photonics courses. I plan to take some of those courses to get basic foundations. Also, I decided to go to ENSEIRB MATMECA to get research experience in RF and microelectronics. My former university (I completed 3/5 years of EE there) focused on applied mathematics to computer networks and energy, quantum computing and DSP.